# Excel Summing Formula setting against month date using SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel

I am trying sum rows that have the same month date. I have a formula that operates with columns but fails when rows are requested. I will show the formulas that I have tried, but I am now stuck. Any advise would be much appreciated.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($A$9:$A$50)=5),$B$9:$B$50)
```

This array works fine with a column

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($A$9:$A$50)=5),$B$9:**$H$50**)
```

see the bold reference which comprises a series of cells set out in rows.

Answer (score 2):

`SUMPRODUCT` normally expects ranges to be the same size but you can get the result you need with a change to the syntax, i.e.

`=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$9:$A$50)=5)*$B$9:$H$50)`

You can't have any text in `B9:H50` otherwise you will get `#VALUE!` error. If you **do** have text in that range then you can use this version, which should ignore the text and give you a result

`=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$9:$A$50)=5)*ISNUMBER($B$9:$H$50),$B$9:$H$50)`

Comment: I was literally about to post the same kind of answer except I used `COLUMN($B$9:$H$50)>0`